# How to set library's path for q custom Qt application

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, module, qt4, mingw

I am running in situation where I have two different versions of Qt installed, the compiled with mingw one, and the other with visual studio.
Now, When I compile my program with Qt MinGW version and run it, I got a message have scrambled text, saying that one of essential Qt modules not loaded.
My question is, how I can set the path to Qt essential modules for my application with C++. I looked at documentation and found [addLibraryPath](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qcoreapplication.html#addLibraryPath) method but it seems like for Qt plugins only.

Comment: If you're using MS VS 2010, it should be in Project Properties. Include directories, Library directories, etc. Also you can set them in MVS VS options.

Comment: I am talking here after compilation, please read my question again.

Comment: I think I'm misunderstood. You have 2 versions of Qt bundle, one is compiled with MinGW and another with MS VS. I got it now. So what's the problem with MS VS one ?! Are you intended to make you application cross-platform ?!

Comment: I don't facing problem in finding include/library paths, rather then, I have difficulty to make my application to load the necessary dll's from a path I define. I hope you understand my goal now.

Comment: I understand that you want to load dlls from a path. But I don't get it why you are going to use 2 different Qt versions, one compiled with MinGW and one with MS VS. What has routed you to change to MinGW or MS VS ?!

Comment: @Amini It is for testing purposes.

Comment: Aha, I'm sorry. Basically, Qt MingGW is compiled with Gnu Compiler and Library Collection I think, but Qt MS VS is compiled with MS VS C++ compiler and is more coupled and matched with Windows. You may need Gnu natives to make it work right.

Comment: I found a [question](http://www.qtforum.org/article/22387/loading-qt-dll-s-from-a-sub-directory.html) have some problem, but no answer yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit**

It seems I misunderstood the question, as SIFE comment that he needs to load Qt modules (like QtGui4.dll), not plugins. The answer for plugins is left here, in case it might help someone.

**Plugins**

Qt loads plugins that are in the `SDK/plugins` by default. The problem is, it finds the wrong SDK first...

If I remember right, Qt first search in the directory `.`. So you can copy the 'plugins' directory near your *.exe : plugins for msvc copied near the msvc-compiled exe, and plugins for gcc near gcc-compiled exe.

If you do not want to copy the `plugins` directory, you can use [setLibraryPaths](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qcoreapplication.html#setLibraryPaths) (not tested, but might work)

Last but not least, you can also use the [qt.conf](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qt-conf.html) approach.

**Modules**

Modules are not dynamically loaded, in the sense that they're part of the dependencies of the application, so they are loaded at exe startup, and not via LoadLibrary. So, the solution is simple: just copy the dlls in the same folder than the one containing the *.exe

Comment: I need to load essential modules of Qt4 like QtGui4.dll and QtCore4.dll, not Qt4 plugins.

Answer (score 0):

Concerning compiler, the proper library/include settings should be done by QMake.
QMake creates your makefile/VS-Project using the libraries found in the same Version Qmake belongs to.

Try calling QMake using the complete path explicitely for each Qt-Version
e.g.

```
c:/myQtMinGwProject>c:/Qt4_mingw/bin/qmake 
c:/myQtVSProject>c:/Qt4_VS2008/bin/qmake -t vcapp
```

Concerning run-time, make sure the dlls for corresponding version are in PATH

I hope it helps

Comment: Adding DLLs to path: either copy them to output directory (my prefered method, so you make sure, all you need is in your output/build directory), or call: "set PATH=%PATH%:c:/myQtDir/bin" You may also set PATH in QtCreator in "Projects/Runtime Settings"